# Stick button to right side of div

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/kn5sH/

What do I need to add in order to stick the button to the right side of the div on the same line as the header?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <h1> Ok </h1>
    <button type='button'>Button</button>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background: purple;
}

div h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

div button {
}
```

More specifically:

1. The right side of the button should be x pixels away from the right
   edge of the div.
2. It should be on the same line as the header.
3. Should be contained in the div (stuff like float or relative
   positioning pops it out of the div visually)

What CSS techniques can be used to do this?  Thanks.

Answer (score 73):

Normally I would recommend floating but from your 3 requirements I would suggest this:

```
position: absolute;
right: 10px;
top: 5px;
```

Don't forget `position: relative;` on the parent div

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kn5sH/2/)

Comment: Thanks, this works great.  I tried this but forgot to the 'top' attribute which pushed it below the div.

Answer (score 39):

Another solution: change margins. Depending on the siblings of the button, `display` should be modified.

```css
button {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 25):

It depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

If you just want to have it on the right, then I'd recommend against using position absolute, because it opens a whole can of worms down the line.

The HTML can also be unchanged:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h1> Ok </h1>
    <button type='button'>Button</button>
</div>
```

the CSS then should be something along the lines of:

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div h1 {
    text-align: center;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-right: -50%;
}

div button {
    float: right;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/azhH5/

If you can change the HTML, then it gets a bit simpler:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <button type='button'>Button</button>
    <h1> Ok </h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

div button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: -50%;
}
```

You can see it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/8WA3k/1/

If you want to have the button on the same line as the Text, you can achieve it by doing this:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <button type='button'>Button</button>
    <h1> Ok </h1>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
div {
    background: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

div button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: -50%;
    margin-top: 2em;
}
```

You an see that in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/EtqVh/1/

Cleary in the lest example you'd have to adjust the margin-top for the specified font-size of the `<h1>`

**EDIT:**

As you can see, it doesn't get popped out of the `<div>`,  it's till inside. this is achieved by two things: the negative margin on the `<button>`, and the `overflow: hidden;` on the `<div>`

**EDIT 2:**

I just saw that you also want it to be a bit away from the margin on the right. That's easily achievable with this method. Just add `margin-right: 1em;` to the `<button>`, like this:

```
div {
    background: purple;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

div button {
    float: right;
    margin-left: -50%;
    margin-top: 2em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}
```

You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/QkvGb/

Comment: Can you elaborate further on how that `overflow: hidden` helps in this situation? and that negative margin too.

Answer (score 6):

```
div {
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question but adding an explanation of the code would be helpful to future readers.

Answer (score 5):

```
<div>
    <h1> Ok </h1>
    <button type='button'>Button</button>
    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
```

css

```
div {
    background: purple;
}

div h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

div button {
    float: right;
    margin-right:10px;

}
```

Comment: Thanks.  This works just as well as the above, I also tried this method but didn't have the 'clear:both' applied under the button element.  I was close!

Answer (score 2):

Use position property

```
style="position: absolute;right:0;top:0"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
margin-left:  auto;
```

was sufficient for me

Answer (score 0):

change the CSS as follows:

```
div button {
position:absolute;
    right:10px;
    top:25px;
}
```